# Getting the $x$ values to generate a list plot for a given function

Tags: plotting, function-construction

I want to plot a function with points and lines. I have to use `ListPlot` to make the plot.

Now, I have no problem getting the $y$ values, but the $x$ values are wrong.
So I want to generate them with a For-loop in my plotting code. But what I've done does not work.

Can someone tell me how to improve it?

```
xk[k_, n_] := (-1 + k*1/(n/2))
xk[4, 7]
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 25 x^2)
f[6]
fk[n_] := Table[f[xk[i, n]], {i, 0, n}]
fk[10]
ListPlot[for[i = 0, i <= 10, i++, {xk[i, 10], Part[fk[10], i]}]]
Plot[fk[xk[x, n], {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Since you apparently know how to use `Table`, try using that instead of `For`.

Answer (score 4):

Another approach. One that I think is not only more concise, but more efficient and more elegant than using `For`.

```
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 25 x^2)
```

The built-in function `Subdivide` can be used to do the subdivision you perform with `xk` and `Table`, so those functions can be dispensed with. So all that is needed to generated the points you want to plot is:

```
fpts[n_] := With[{pts = Subdivide[-1, 1, n]}, Transpose[{pts, f /@ pts}]]
```

The plot is just

```
ListLinePlot[fpts[41], Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Just for the record: `f[x]` is the (in)famous Runge function: an infinitely differentiable function for which equidistant interpolating points on the `x`-axis give increasingly poorer polynomial approximations (especially toward the endpoints). (But the OP and you proabably already know that.)

Comment: @murray, Well, I didn't know it. Not a mathematician. Thanks for the additional info about the problem domain.