# Create a Vandermonde matrix

Tags: matrix

I want to create a $n \times n$ [`Vandermonde matrix`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VandermondeMatrix.html).

How could I set up a matrix, `vMatrix` so I can just use
`vMatrix[5]` and get an element of the matrix?

Do I have to set up a $n \times n$ null matrix first to build it?

````
xk[k_, n_] := (-1 + k*1/(n/2))
xk[4, 7]
f[x_] := 1/(1 + 25 x^2)
f[6]
fk[n_] := Table[f[xk[i, n]], {i, 0, n}]
fk[10]
PlotPoint[x_] := 
 ListPlot[Table[{xk[i, x], Part[fk[x], i + 1]}, {i, 0, x}]]
PlotLine[x_] := Plot[f[i], {i, xk[0, x], xk[x, x]}]
Show[PlotLine[10], PlotPoint[10]]

getMatrix[N_] := Table[f[i]
```
````

Comment: The code in this post looks very much like the [code posted here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/210529/3066) under the user name "Rack Cloud".

Comment: yeah i have 2 stackaccounts due to the fact that some subforums have a question limit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the $x$ values to generate a list plot for a given function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210529/getting-the-x-values-to-generate-a-list-plot-for-a-given-function)

Comment: Not quite the solution that's the easiest to understand, but you can use `DesignMatrix` for this. E.g., `DesignMatrix[Array[{x[#], 1} &, 5], y^Range[5], y]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html)

```
vMatrix[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Array[x[#1]^(#2 - 1) &, {n, n}]

Format[x[n_]] := Subscript[x, n]

(mat = vMatrix[5]) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
Det[mat] // Simplify
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To enable the argument to also be a vector, add to the definition

```
vMatrix[v_?VectorQ] :=
 #^Range[0, Length[v] - 1] & /@ v

mat == vMatrix[Array[x, 5]]

(* True *)
```

Comment: Solved it with table don't know the Suberscript function will read through that.

Answer (score 9):

Just for the sake of some variety:

```
vandermonde[n_Integer?Positive] := 
 Outer[Power, Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, n}], Range[0, n - 1]]
```

Comment: +1. For further variety, I'd probably write a general-purpose `vandermonde` and apply to my `x` array: `vandermonde[x_] := Outer[Power, x, Range[0, Length@x - 1]]`

Answer (score 7):

> I want to create a $n \times n$ [`Vandermonde matrix`](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VandermondeMatrix.html).

There is an *undocumented* function for this:

```
LinearAlgebra`Private`VandermondeMatrix[Array[x, 5], Transpose -> True]
   {{1, x[1], x[1]^2, x[1]^3, x[1]^4},
    {1, x[2], x[2]^2, x[2]^3, x[2]^4},
    {1, x[3], x[3]^2, x[3]^3, x[3]^4},
    {1, x[4], x[4]^2, x[4]^3, x[4]^4},
    {1, x[5], x[5]^2, x[5]^3, x[5]^4}}
```

---

**Edit 7/19/2022**

In the current version, the following should be evaluated instead:

```
StructuredArray`VandermondeMatrix[Array[x, 5], List]
```